# JavaFX Mac Menu Name

Tags: java, macos, javafx, menubar

I've been using [JarWrapper](https://github.com/stbachmann/JarWrapper) to make a Mac OS X application bundle that contains a bundled JRE. When I run the application, the menubar name is correct, however the menu items within contain the class name (see screenshot below):
[image]

I am using `-Xdock:name="VisUAL"` as a VM argument, and having looked elsewhere, this alone should be enough to fix the menu item names.

The JRE bundled is 1.8.0_45. I am running Mac OS X 10.10.

Has anyone else faced this issue? If so, how have you resolved it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem with our application. The solution we are using for now is to move the class file to the base folder. So not inside a package.